# Detect when a DOM node is removed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to write a directive which will ensure that only one of its elements will remain active at any given time.

Directive: showOnlyOne
Description: attaches to a dom node and ensures that only one dom node with this directive attached can be visible at a time.
Usage:

```
<body>
<div id="one" show-only-one></div>

<section> 
<div id="two" show-only-one></div>
</section>
</body>
```

In this case, the one that would show would be "two"...  Now imagine that due to an external event the section element gets a jqLite .remove() called on it.  Now how do I detect that "two" has been removed and then reactivate "one" so it will be shown?

```
angular.module('SWS')
.directive('swsOnlyOne', ['$log', '$interval', function($log, $interval) {
  var billies = [];
  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    if (billies.length > 0) {
      _.each(billies, function(b) {
        b.css('visibility', 'hidden');
      });
    }
    elem[0].addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', function(ev) {
      // THIS DOM EVENT WILL NEVER FIRE...
      if ('hidden' != elem.css('visibility')) {
        billies.splice(billies.indexOf(elem), 1);
        billies[billies.length].css('visibility', 'visible');
      }
    }, false);

    billies.push(elem);
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Why dont you put one and two in an array, and use ng-change to track changes if one of them has been removed?

Comment: When you removed that element from DOM as you said in description jqLite.remove() at that time use $broadcast/emit(passed required data) event and add listner using $on you can listen that

Comment: @PradeepMahdevu even with that hint, I'm still not smart enough to understand how one would use ngChange to accomplish the task in this situation.  Just to further clarify, I have no control over the jqLite.remove() that gets called, so I can't add my own event broadcast when it occurs.  (It's happening in another framework.)

Comment: Maybe you can checkout accordion directive for angular bootstrap project.

Comment: what other framework? Sounds like an `X-Y` problem and you should provide more details as to the actual situation and higher level problem

Comment: @JayPrime2012 angular.element(document).bind("DOMNodeRemoved", function(e){
        alert("Removed: " + e.target.nodeName);
    });
Used it if you really want to catch which element is removed.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way you listen with angular (best practices) is with `scope.on("$destroy", fn)`
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy

```
$scope.on("$destroy", function(event){
   // cleanup
});

// but can also be used on elements
elem.on("$destroy", function(event){
   // cleanup    
});
```